# Server disk de-allocated itself - why?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

We had an emergency situation happen overnight last month.  A virtualised server (Server 2008R2) running under VMWare 6.5  experienced its D drive disappearing and becoming 250GB of unallocated space. As this was the data drive for our SQL server this was quite an emergency.  We eventually got all the data back via a program called Ease-US, but are at a total loss to figure out how it can have happened. 
Nothing in the Windows, VEEAM, VMWare or SAN logs give any clues. There is no evidence of malware hitting master boot records either.

Any ideas what could have caused this?

Comment: Is the failed disk still in the array? Have you checked the baremetal for disk issues?

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question at StackExchange Server Fault.

Comment: No disk shows any sign of having actually failed - the baremetal SAN disks are all green and good.